# Creating a composite independent variable from two categorical variables?

Tags: regression, model, composite

I have two predictor variables, one of which has measures how often a participant smokes in 5 levels (< 1x/week, 1x/week, 3-4x/week, everyday, and +2x/day). The other predictor is a categorical variable which measures whether a participant smoked a specific cigarette brand, values range from 0-2 (meaning that they either smoked 2 of the specific brands, 1, or none).

For context -my research question is related to whether self-reported smoking frequency is related to cigarette preferences and attitudes (e.g., recall of tobacco brands, etc.). My outcome variables will be ordinal and a count variable.
I'm wondering what the best way to go about combining these predictors into a composite variable to effectively create an index of smoking?

Comment: The ability to answer this adequately depends on your research question.

Comment: Based on the information you’ve added, why is the way to create this “index” not the number you get from (ordinal, softmax) regression?